# Using scipy.optimize to perform logistic regression for OCR

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, ocr, logistic-regression

I am trying to teach myself different machine learning techniques so i figured I would start working on optical character recognition. I got this to work in octave but I want to leverage python because I figure it will be faster.

When I run my code "cost_fcn()" and "gradient_descent()" work correctly by themselves but when I try to use optimizer to train theta it errors out. I have attached the traceback below, and below that my code.

I am using the mnist training set reworked by pjreddie at: https://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_code.py", line 115, in <module>
    optimization = opt.minimize(cost_fcn, initial_theta, args = (X_t,y_t,lambda_t), method = 'BFGS', jac = gradient_descent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 441, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 847, in _minimize_bfgs
    gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 289, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "./test_code.py", line 87, in gradient_descent
    grad[0] = (1/m)*np.matmul(X[:,0].conj().transpose(),(np.subtract(h,y)))
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (1)
```

And now my code:

```
import csv
from PIL import Image
import sys
import numpy as np
import math
import cmath
import scipy.optimize as opt

size = 28           # images are 28x28 pixels

test_images = []            # 10000 images
test_images_labels = []     # 10000 labels

train_images = []           # 60000 images
train_images_labels = []    # 60000 labels

# open and read train images file
with open('mnist_train.csv','r') as f:
    mnist_train = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    for image in mnist_train:
        train_images.append(list(map(int,image[1:])))
        train_images_labels.append(image[0])

print("Image training set loaded... ")

# open and read test images file
with open('mnist_test.csv','r') as f:
    mnist_test = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    for image in mnist_test:
        test_images.append(image[1:])
        test_images_labels.append(image[0])

print("Image test set loaded... ")

##########################################
# Multi-Class Logistic Classifier
#
#


# Define the activation function
def activation_fcn(z):
    g = np.divide(1.0, (1.0 + np.exp(-z)))
    return g

# Define the cost function
def cost_fcn(theta, X, y, lambda_term): 
    m = len(y)      # number of examples
    J = 0           # initialize cost term

    h = activation_fcn(np.matmul(X,theta))
    theta_sq = np.power(theta[1:],2)
    abs_log = np.log(np.abs(np.subtract(1,h)))

    J_unreg_nonsum = np.multiply(y, np.log(h)) + np.multiply((np.subtract(1,y)), abs_log)
    J_unreg = (-1/m)*J_unreg_nonsum.sum(axis=0)

    sum_theta_sq = theta_sq.sum(axis=0)
    reg_term = (lambda_term/(2*m))*sum_theta_sq
    J = J_unreg + reg_term

    return J

def gradient_descent(theta, X, y, lambda_term):
    m = len(y)
    grad_size = X.shape
    grad = np.zeros((grad_size[1],1), float)

    h = activation_fcn(np.matmul(X,theta))  
    grad[0] = (1/m)*np.matmul(X[:,0].conj().transpose(),(np.subtract(h,y)))
    grad[1:] = (1/m)*np.matmul(X[:,1:].conj().transpose(),(np.subtract(h,y))) + (lambda_term/m)*theta[1:,:]

    return grad.flatten()


###############################################################################################################
### test using the numpy matrix object 

## initializations
theta_t = np.matrix('-2; -1; 1; 2')
X_t = np.matrix('1.0 0.1 0.6 1.1; 1.0 0.2 0.7 1.2; 1.0 0.3 0.8 1.3; 1.0 0.4 0.9 1.4; 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.5')
y_t = np.matrix('1; 0; 1; 0; 1')
lambda_t = 3

## test regularized cost func (IT WORKS!)
test_cost = cost_fcn(theta_t, X_t, y_t, lambda_t)
print("The cost is: %d" % test_cost)

## test gradient descent (IT WORKS!)
test_grad = gradient_descent(theta_t, X_t, y_t, lambda_t)
print("The gradient is: ")
print(test_grad)

print("made it to optimizations")
## optimization of theta
m,n = X_t.shape
initial_theta = np.zeros(n, float)
optimization = opt.minimize(cost_fcn, initial_theta, args = (X_t,y_t,lambda_t), method = 'BFGS', jac = gradient_descent)

print(optimization)
###############################################################################################################
```

I would really appreciate some help on this. I believe the error has something to do with how I am feeding arguments to "opt.minimize()" but I have been unsuccessful in solving the issue.